# How to have EditText disabled for manual input but still receiving data from built in barcode scanner?

Tags: android, android-edittext, barcode-scanner

I am using one of those devices that have built in barcode scanner.

Is it posible on Android to have a EditText disabled for manual input, but able to recieve data from built in barcode scanner?

Comment: Just put editTextReference.setEnabled(false) and when you want to set data you can use editTextReference.setText(dataYouWantToShow)

Comment: I think you can use `android:editable="false"`

Comment: Or `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: Yes, but how should I receive data from scanner in that case? 
(when edittext is focused it receives data from scanner as if it comes from keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

disable it for click and focus but programmatically add to it the result of your scanner.

On your layout use the following attributes on the EditText:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

and then for the result:

```
yourEditText.setText(scannerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that by overriding onKey method on OnKeyListener:

`editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {  
       // you have to return false on ENTER (buildIn scanner) 
       //or Back key to change activity
       //you can add ur keycodes here
           if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
               return false;
           } else {
               return true;
           }
       }
   });`